# The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, platform, cordova-ios

I'm running under cordova@7.1.0, cordova-ios@4.5.2.
Installed platforms: ios 4.5.2.

I run npm install, bower install then cordova prepare ios and i get the following error: 
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'unorm'
Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported.)

The solution is to cordova platform rm ios and cordova platform add ios. But i have to do this each time i checkout my project from git ...

Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You should not put the `platforms` (and `plugins`) folder into source-control. Reinstalling the platform after a fresh checkout is the expected behaviour.

The files in the `platforms` folder are created dynamically which is why they should not be in source control.

Comment: We have the same issue as OP and we DO submit platforms and plugins to source-control - because otherwise plugins installation breaks everytime we try to reinstall them in a bunch and we end up spending hours in dependency-hell ... Might be that we need to update to the latest version of cordova, but to be honest at this point I'd rather refactor into another framework than continue using cordova, it's too unreliable and buggy.